# Why my hexo can't load the plugin hexo-generator-json-content

Tags: node.js, plugins, hexo

I use
`npm i hexo-generator-json-content --save`
to install this plugin it will install success
[image]
but when I run the `hexo g`
It will be like this
[image]
My npm version is 2.15.8
node.js version is 4.4.7
OS is Windows

Answer (score 0):

try to update your node.js version , more than 6.2